# axis 1.4 linux help - happyaxis not happy AXISCLASSPATH all wrong?

Tags: linux, classpath, tomcat6, axis, turnkeylinux.org

I'm trying to use axis 1.4 on turnkey linux tomcat6 appliance.

Short version is that assuming it's the root of the problem; what is the correct way to set AXISCLASSPATH on debian?

Long version is:

axis.war deploys correctly.  I've added AXIS_HOME and AXIS_LIB to etc/environment like so:

```
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat6"
CATALINA_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat6"
CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xms384M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26"
AXIS_HOME="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/axis"
AXIS_LIB="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/lib"
```

and all echo correctly. tomcat6 admin page shows axis running, /localhost/axis loads fine but happyaxis is kicking:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /happyaxis.jsp at line 45
>
> 42:      */ 43:     Class classExists(String classname) { 44:
>   try { 45:             return Class.forName(classname); 46:         }
>   catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 47:             return null; 48:
>   }
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/ibm/wsdl/factory/WSDLFactoryImpl : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0 (unable to load class com.ibm.wsdl.factory.WSDLFactoryImpl)  org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
>     org.apache.jsp.happyaxis_jsp._jspService(happyaxis_jsp.java:808)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/ibm/wsdl/factory/WSDLFactoryImpl : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0 (unable to load class com.ibm.wsdl.factory.WSDLFactoryImpl)  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
>     org.apache.jsp.happyaxis_jsp.classExists(happyaxis_jsp.java:34)
>     org.apache.jsp.happyaxis_jsp.probeClass(happyaxis_jsp.java:77)
>     org.apache.jsp.happyaxis_jsp.needClass(happyaxis_jsp.java:151)
>     org.apache.jsp.happyaxis_jsp._jspService(happyaxis_jsp.java:650)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

I have used axis in the past on ubuntu and had issues with openjdk. So I tried removing openjdk and installed sun-java-6 and get the same error.

According to every bit of documentation I've seen, $AXISCLASSPATH needs to point to the axis/lib .jar files and may be the issue but the apache documentation is very old:

> Unix users have to do something similar. Below we have installed AXIS
>   into /usr/axis and are using the bash shell. See your shell's
>   documentation for differences. To make variables permeate you will
>   need to add them to your shell's startup (dot) files. Again, see your
>   shell's documentation.
>
> ```
> set AXIS_HOME=/usr/axis
> set AXIS_LIB=$AXIS_HOME/lib
> set AXISCLASSPATH=$AXIS_LIB/axis.jar:$AXIS_LIB/commons-discovery.jar:
>   $AXIS_LIB/commons-logging.jar:$AXIS_LIB/jaxrpc.jar:$AXIS_LIB/saaj.jar:
>   $AXIS_LIB/log4j-1.2.8.jar:$AXIS_LIB/xml-apis.jar:$AXIS_LIB/xercesImpl.jar
> export AXIS_HOME; export AXIS_LIB; export AXISCLASSPATH
> ```

when I deploy, xercesImpl.jar is not present in the lib director and log4-1.2.8.jar is just log4j.jar

I copied xercesImpl from elsewhere in the file system and after an exhaustive search I have tried setting this variable from the command line, etc/environment, tomcat6.sh and a few others, all without success.

The only method I found that will echo correctly was with the command line code:

```
export AXISCLASSPATH:$AXIS_LIB/axis.jar;$AXIS_LIB/commons-discover.jar;$AXIS_LIB/commons-logging.jar;$AXIS_LIB/jaxrpc.jar;$AXIS_LIB/saaj.jar;$AXIS_LIB/log4j.jar
```

still no change.  as a stab in the dark I copied wsdl4j.jar from elsewhere on the filesystem to /lib and added it to the above export command and still no joy

Answer (score 0):

"Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 " means "JVM version too low; 51== Java7".

Steve

(who wrote happyaxis.jsp 10 years ago)